# How to get the size and position of edge labels?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to place edge labels on a specified position in my graph. I found that i can manipulate the labels position with `text-margin-x` and `text-margin-y` but to calculate the needed margins I need to know the current position of the label. I already tried using `source-label` and the position of the source node but this means that `text-events` no longer work.

Is there a way to get/calculate the position of the label on segments edges?

Furthermore to help me align certain labels I need to know how to get/calculate the bounding box of the edge label, is there a way to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found that i can use `edge.midpoint()` to get the location of the label.

For the size of the label I use a workaround where I render everything once to get the `labelHeight` and `labelWidth` from `rstyle` and then I rerender everything correctly.